# Web Socket sending and receiving data in multiple Fragments and Activity

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I am using websocket for the first time, It's a Uber kind of application. I am receiving data from the socket , the socket connection and receiver is in common class, but i am confused how to pass data for the particular activity or fragment in a optimized way. As per my knowledge i thought of using Broadcast receiver in required class, but its not a good way ...So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a good solution i don't think it's the ultimate but, it works faster than Brad cast receiver.

1. I created a Interface in Main Activity, with a method that send the received data.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

       SendData sendData;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }

       public interface SendData {
           public void sendData(String data);
       }

   }
   ```
2. In Fragment Class where i need the response from Main Activity, I implemented the above Interface of Main Activity.

   ```
   public class Storage extends Fragment implements MainActivity.SendData{

       View view;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_info_fragment,container,false);
           return view;
       }

       @Override
       public void SendData(String data) {
          String dataReceived = data;
       }

   }
   ```
3. When i receive the data in Main Activity i will get the current fragment, if i want data to be sent to that fragment then i should have implemented the Main Activity Interface in that fragment and Create a casting in Main Class when i have the data and notify the fragment with the value

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

       @Override
       public void notifySocketMessage(final String message) {
           if(message != null){
               dataPasser = // define the fragment class name where you need to send the data.
               dataPasser.onDataPass(message); // add the message to the notifier
           }
       }

   }
   ```